# Remove CSS Class on 'Drop' Event - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, events, drag-and-drop, drop

I'm building a file uploader and when I drag files over the target area I have a class that is added on `dragover` and removed on `dragleave`. This essentially changes the border color of the drop zone so that the user knows when they can drop the files. This is done by adding and removing a 'drop' class.

I'm trying to make it so when the user drops the actual files into the drop zone the `drop` event also removes the 'drop' class that is added on dragover (so the border goes back to its original state), but I can't get this to work?

Codepen is: https://codepen.io/emilychews/pen/OJpwzej

Any help really appreciated.

```js
var dropZone = document.getElementById("drop-zone");

// change border on file dragover by adding the class "drop"
dropZone.addEventListener(
  "dragover",
  function (e) {
    e.target.classList.add("drop");
  },
  false
);

// remove border by removing the class "drop" when user leaves the drop zone
dropZone.addEventListener(
  "dragleave",
  function (e) {
    e.target.classList.remove("drop");
  },
  false
);

// -- PART THAT ISN'T WORKING
// also remove border by removing the class "drop" when files are dropped
dropZone.addEventListener(
  "drop",
  function (e) {
    e.target.classList.remove("drop");
  },
  false
);
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

.inner-drop-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.inner-drop-wrapper.drop {
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="inner-drop-wrapper" id="drop-zone">
  Drag and drop files here
</div>
```

Comment: so the color that changed to red on drop needs to revert back to grey correct?

Comment: @seriously yes that is correct. After the files are dropped it needs to revert to it's original border.

Comment: It's working for me when I run the code snippet, not sure if that's due to a recent edit or not.

Comment: @Mordred The code 'works' on dragover / dragleave, but after you drop files into the dropzone the border stays red. I need to change back to the original border after the drop has happened.

Comment: @Anna_p Got it. Is the `drop` callback even being called?

Comment: @Mordred I don't think it is because when I put a console.log message in the function it doesn't show in the console.

Comment: did @rm_ answer fix it or do you still need help

Comment: @seriously The side effect of the solution below is console.log() messages don't show - which isn't ideal obviously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to allow drop in your div. To achieve that, you need to add

```
e.preventDefault();
```

as the first line of your dragover callback function. This will enable your drop event to fire properly.

```js
var dropZone = document.getElementById("drop-zone");

// change border on file dragover by adding the class "drop"
dropZone.addEventListener(
  "dragover",
  function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('dragover');
    e.target.classList.add("drop");
  },
  false
);

// remove border by removing the class "drop" when user leaves the drop zone
dropZone.addEventListener(
  "dragleave",
  function (e) {
    console.log('dragleave');
    e.target.classList.remove("drop");
  },
  false
);

// -- PART THAT ISN'T WORKING
// also remove border by removing the class "drop" when files are dropped
dropZone.addEventListener(
  "drop",
  function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('drop');
    e.target.classList.remove("drop");
  },
  false
);
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

.inner-drop-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.inner-drop-wrapper.drop {
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="inner-drop-wrapper" id="drop-zone">
  Drag and drop files here
</div>
```

From MDN documentation

> If you want to allow a drop, you must prevent the default handling by cancelling both the dragenter and dragover events. You can do this either by returning false from attribute-defined event listeners, or by calling the event's preventDefault() method. The latter may be more feasible in a function defined in a separate script.

[MDN - Specifying Drop Targets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_Drag_and_Drop_API/Drag_operations#droptargets)

Comment: Ah - I thought I was meant to do that in the 'drop' event. Thanks very much.

Comment: You may have to add e.preventDefault() in drop callback, firefox needs that otherwise it redirects to the dropped file location. I've updated my answer, works fine in chrome and firefox (latest versions).

Comment: The problem I have with this is that it prevents any console.log() messages. If this is the only solution I'll have to go with it (i'll obviously turn off log messages when it's finished anyway) but it would be nice to find a solution that still allows console.log messages to work.

Comment: I don't see how this solution blocks console.log. If preventDefault blocked the execution of the rest of the callback, then the drop css class wouldn't be removed as well. I've updated the answer to include the console logs.

Comment: Hi @rm_ This issue was do to with a propagation problem I think - now I've added return:false it's working. Thanks for your help.